# Borderless form cannot be minimize by clicking on the taskbar application icon

Tags: delphi, winapi, vcl, delphi-10.4-sydney, systemmenu

I have a Delphi VCL application with the following settings:

```
BorderIcons = []
BorderStyle = bsNone
```

I have then already implemented various functions such as minimizing, closing, etc. via buttons. Now I've noticed that when I minimize my application and then click on its taskbar button, it maximizes again normally.

However, when I click on the taskbar entry again, nothing happens. Normally, an application is then minimized.

If I switch the `BorderStyle` back to `bsSingle`, then this works fine. What do I need to do to make this work for a borderless application?

Comment: According to Marco Cantú this works as designed: https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-27576

Comment: So there is no solution except this workaround?
As a workaround you can go to Project > View Source and remove line "Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True;", also you can set Application.Title there.

Comment: Press `Shift` while right-clicking on your task button to check the system menu for the current status (windows can only be minimized when being maximized or restored, otherwise that menu item is deactivated) or if that menu even has the "Minimize" entry. Cannot reproduce with Delphi 7. Also I don't get why you not even allow `BorderIcons.biSystemMenu`.

Comment: When I right-click+shift on the icon in the taskbar, nothing happens. No context menu opens. Also setting `BorderIcons` to `biSystemMenu` does not change anything. Only if I comment out the line `Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True;` it works.